# Looping through Elements

Tags: jquery, function, loops

Hey guys, I want to make a function loop over all elements that have the class of ".block-header-tabs" and do the following:

```
$(function(){

function cssTabs(){

var firstTab = $(".block-header-tabs").find("a:first");
var firstBlock = $(".block-header-tabs").find("a:first").attr('href');
$(firstBlock).parent().css({position: "relative"});
$(firstBlock).css({position: "absolute", zIndex: "2"})
$(firstBlock).siblings().css({opacity: "0", position: "absolute", top: "0", zIndex: "1"});
$(firstTab).addClass("tab-current");
$(firstTab).siblings().addClass("tab-noncurrent");

}

cssTabs();

$(".block-header-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("tab-current").addClass("tab-noncurrent");
    $(this).removeClass("tab-noncurrent").addClass("tab-current")
    var clickedTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(clickedTab).siblings().css({zIndex: "1"}).stop(0,0).animate({opacity:"0"}, function(){
        $(clickedTab).siblings().css({display:"none"});
    });
    $(clickedTab).css({display:"block", zIndex:"2"}).stop(0,0).animate({opacity:"1"});

    return false;

});

});
```

here is a link to live example so you can check it out yourselves :)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2878602/moviezet/index.html

thanks

Comment: by the way to explain the link, as you can see that the function works only on the first instance of .block-header-tabs not on the second one right below it. It isn't styled as it should be :(

Comment: My problem is that I want that function to repeat so that It does the styling for all elements, currently it's only working on the first instance of .block-header-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I resolved this myself, turns out that I cannot use a:first to target the main block if I want to use .each() on it. :) here is the fixed code if anyone is interested:

```
$(".block-header-tabs").each(function(){
    $($(this).find("a:first").attr('href')).css({position: "absolute", zIndex: "2"})
    $($(this).find("a:first").attr('href')).siblings().css({opacity: "0", position: "absolute", top: "0", zIndex: "1"});
    $($(this).find("a:first").attr('href')).parent().css({position: "relative"});
});
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
$(function(){
  function cssTabs($this){
    var firstTab = $this(".block-header-tabs").find("a:first");
    var firstBlock = $this(".block-header-tabs").find("a:first").attr('href');
    $(firstBlock).parent().css({position: "relative"});
    $(firstBlock).css({position: "absolute", zIndex: "2"})
    $(firstBlock).siblings().css({opacity: "0", position: "absolute", top: "0", zIndex: "1"});
    $(firstTab).addClass("tab-current");
    $(firstTab).siblings().addClass("tab-noncurrent");
  }

  $('.block-header-tabs').each(function(index) {
    cssTabs($(this));
    $(this).find("a").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("tab-current").addClass("tab-noncurrent");
      $(this).removeClass("tab-noncurrent").addClass("tab-current")
      var clickedTab = $(this).attr('href');
      $(clickedTab).siblings().css({zIndex: "1"}).stop(0,0).animate({opacity:"0"}, function(){
          $(clickedTab).siblings().css({display:"none"});
      });
      $(clickedTab).css({display:"block", zIndex:"2"}).stop(0,0).animate({opacity:"1"});
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm it seems to break everything? :S

Comment: 26Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
cssTabs//-private-/scripts/site-functions.js:26
(anonymous function)/-private-/scripts/site-functions.js:36
eachajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:30
c.fn.c.eachajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:24
(anonymous function)//-private-/scripts/site-functions.js:35
readyajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:26
L

Comment: debug your script , it should work , main idea is   $('.block-header-tabs').each(function(index) {}); which loops

Answer (score 0):

```
function cssTabs(element){
    var firstTab = element.find("a:first");
    var firstBlock = element.find("a:first").attr('href');
    $(firstBlock).parent().css({position: "relative"});
    $(firstBlock).css({position: "absolute", zIndex: "2"})
    $(firstBlock).siblings().css({opacity: "0", position: "absolute", top: "0", zIndex: "1"});
    $(firstTab).addClass("tab-current");
    $(firstTab).siblings().addClass("tab-noncurrent");
}



 $(function(){
    $.each($('.block-header-tabs'), function(i, el){
        cssTabs($(this));
        $(this).find('a').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("tab-current").addClass("tab-noncurrent");
            $(this).removeClass("tab-noncurrent").addClass("tab-current");
            var clickedTab = $(this).attr('href');
            $(clickedTab).siblings().css({
                zIndex: "1"
            }).stop(0,0).animate({
                opacity:"0"
            }, function(){
                $(clickedTab).siblings().css({display:"none"});
            });
            $(clickedTab).css({display:"block", zIndex:"2"}).stop(0,0).animate({opacity:"1"});
            return false;
        })    
    });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function